# How to describe a stuttering video because of a low frame rate?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs

I have to describe this video. It has a very slow frame rate but is otherwise good.

Answer (score 18):

You can say :

> *Cette vidéo est saccadée*.
>
> *Cette vidéo présente une image saccadée*.