# Comment éviter l'anglicisme « lag / laguer » ?

Tags: informatique, anglicismes

A la lecture de [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/how-to-describe-a-stuttering-video-because-of-a-low-frame-rate), il m'est revenu le cruel manque d'une alternative pour un autre terme archi-classique dans le contexte du web, notamment concernant le jeu en ligne : **le lag**.

> **Ca *lague*. Il y a beaucoup de *lag*.** (pour parler d'un retard de mise à jour de l'affichage du à une mauvaise connectivité ou à une surcharge des serveurs concernés)

Comment faire pour rester clair sans angliciser encore un peu plus ce contexte qui l'est déjà beaucoup ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, il me semble que tu as raison, j'ai appliqué ta proposition.

Comment: Anecdotiquement, entendu aujourd'hui à la cantine de mon boulot, dans la file du self : *« Pff y'a pas trop de monde mais pourtant ça lague grave. »*. Oui, ce sont surtout des boites d'informatique dans le coin mais quand même... j'ai souri.

Comment: Le terme que j'entends le plus souvent dans ce contexte est _réactivité_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans un contexte familier, je dirais bien ***ça traîne***. Cette formulation calque vaguement l'anglais (*lag behind* = traîner derrière). Contrairement à *être lent* ou *ramer*, il y a une connotation associée plus à la latence qu'à la vitesse d'exécution. Attention, ce n'est pas un choix de formulation courante.

S'il faut un nom, je préfère [délai](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/5755). *Retard* que tu utilises dans ta description est aussi possible, et peut être un verbe (« l'affichage retarde »).

Dans un contexte plus formel, *latence* est bien le terme technique adapté.

Comment: Et dans cette veine, on dirait *à la traine* pour *laggy* ? J'aime assez également, bonne réponse.

Answer (score 14):

J'utilise en général : **ça rame**.

Le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ramer) confirme :

> **ramer** : Être lent en parlant d’un ordinateur.

Comment: +1 je pense que `ça rame` est la traduction la plus courante.

Comment: Je ne suis pas convaincu : *ça rame* me semble désigner une lenteur de *mon poste client*, or j'essaie ici de désigner une lenteur du réseau ou du serveur distant...

Comment: @RomainVALERI, _le réseau rame_ si tu veux être plus précis sur la source.

Comment: @RomainVALERI : je l'ai entendu utilisé pour parler d'une vidéo Youtube qui ramait également.

Comment: @CédricJulien Oui, j'ai moi aussi déjà rencontré ce genre d'emploi, mais je trouve qu'il prête à confusion.

Comment: *Eh ben di-donc ça **rame dur !*** pour *Dites donc cher collègue, le trafic est **très ralenti** en ce moment !*

Answer (score 9):

Ce délai entre une action et ses conséquences est la [*latence*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/latence) (quoi qu'en dise le TLFi, ce sens est utilisé ailleurs qu'en psychologie), mais je ne connais pas de nom informel. (Note l'anglais plus technique utilise *latency*.)

Comment: Un peu technique mais pas mal pour traduire le substantif. En revanche : *Ca late* ?!

Comment: Je ne vois pas. Et le français ne fabrique pas aussi facilement des verbes à partir de substantifs et des substantifs à partir de verbes que l'anglais.

Comment: @RomainVALERI « Quelle latence ! » ?

Answer (score 5):

Je dirais que "c'est lent" ou que "ça réponds pas". Voir que "la connexion est pourrie/foireuse".

Comment: Par comparaison avec les autres réponses ces quelques propositions me semblent bien plus naturelles. Si l'on excepte « ça lague » (car  visiblement c'est une transgression), ce sont probablement celles que je m'attendrais à entendre dans le cas décrit.

Answer (score 3):

Par analogie avec le téléphone, j'ai déjà rencontré *délai*

> « Il y a beaucoup de délai. »

par contre pour un emploi verbal, ça ne semble pas convenir. Dans ce cas, le plus simple est peut-être de dire que

> « Le serveur est lent. »

ou que

> « La ligne est lente. »

Comment: J'aime bien *délai* ! Je n'y avais pas pensé en effet... ça ne correspondra peut-être pas à tous les emplois, mais je conserve, merci à toi.

Answer (score 1):

Si on différencie les deux d'un point de vue technique (ramer et laguer) et qu'on veut être pointilleux :

Ramer devrait être utilisé lorsqu'il s'agit de notre PC qui est lent (peu d'image par secondes par exemple, ou un programme qui prend longtemps à s'ouvrir, à réagir). (cela fait référence au RAM se trouvant dans le PC)

Alors que le lag (laguer) est fort différent, le PC réagit généralement toujours de façon fluide mais le serveur distant (le lag implique qu'on est sur le net) prend longtemps à répondre, ou il peut paraitre répondre de façon hachée.

Le français ne traduit pas toujours certains mots et utilise parfois/souvent directement le mot anglais.

Comment: Observations justes me semble-t-il, mais la réponse n'est pas clairement donnée. Tu suggères l'usage du terme francisé, {substantif *le lag* / verbe *laguer*} si j'ai bien compris ? Car oui c'est une des possibilités, en effet.

Comment: D'ailleurs tiens, ça me fait penser au couple *a dog / un dogue* ... lequel est hérité de l'autre ? Si quelqu'un sait c'est un parallèle intéressant.

Answer (score 0):

*Ça rame* est évidemment l'équivalent le plus répandu. S'il fallait distinguer entre des ramages locaux et réseaux, je dirais que le PC *rame* et que le serveur *lambine*.